# Prove $\sin^{2m}\alpha\cdot\cos^{2n}\alpha\leq\frac{m^m n^n}{(m+n)^{(m+n)}}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> If $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers, Prove: $$\sin^{2m}\alpha\cos^{2n}\alpha\leq\frac{m^mn^n}{(m+n)^{(m+n)}}$$
>   Additional info:We should only use AM-GM inequality.We can use Trigonometry identities.

*Things I have done so far:* for reaching something useful about $\sin^{2m}\alpha\cos^{2n}\alpha$, I tried to do$$\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha\geq 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha $$

powering to $m$ $$\frac{1}{4}=\left(\frac{\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha}{2}\right)^m\geq 2\sin^{2m}\alpha\cos^{2m}\alpha$$

and I stuck here.And for $ \dfrac {m^mn^n} {(m+n)^{(m+n)}} $ I don't know what to do.(Binomial theorem maybe?)

Comment: What I'd try: Put $\cos^2\alpha=:p$, $\sin^2\alpha=:q$. Then $p$, $q$ are both nonnegative, and $p+q=1$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter,i wrote the two am-gm inequalities and used that fact.did i missed your point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $m$ number of $\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}m$ and $n$ number of $\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha}n$

As each of the term $\ge0$ for real $\alpha;$
using  [AM, GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

$$\frac{m\cdot\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}m+n\cdot\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha}n}{m+n}\ge \left[\left(\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}m\right)^m\left(\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha}n\right)^n\right]^{\dfrac1{m+n}}$$

Comment: @user2838619, Thanks your observation